Do I need TLP on Ubuntu?
I am currently using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.
I have installed it on a thinkpad x1 carbon gen7 and p14s gen4 amd.
I haven't installed Ubuntu for a long time, so I don't know much about it yet.
It told me to install TLP, so I did.
I'm currently using a p14s gen4 amd and it's just as stuttery and slow as the carbon gen7.
The settings and program installations are all the same.
I think the P14S is slower after installing TLP.
Is this correct?
Incidentally, I'm not sure if there is much difference between Ubuntu's power management and TLP.
I wonder if the TLP installation is still valid today.
Does Ubuntu power management drain a lot of battery?

What exactly is TLP?
